# Homology of structure maps for loop spaces!

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

If $X$ is an $n$-fold loop spaces then the theory tells us that for $j<n$ there are structure maps
$$\theta_j:F(\mathbb{R}^n,j)\times_{\Sigma_j}X^{\times j}\to X.$$
At a given prime $p$, the homology of $\theta_p$ then is used to define  Kudo-Araki operations $Q_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p$-homology. Now, my question is that what happens to the other structure maps? Is it that if $q$ is prime to $p$ then $\theta_q$ would induce zero operations, and if $m$ is divisible by $p$ (in fact a power of $p$) then what we get is expressible in terms of $\theta_p$? I think this is well known and wonder if anything on this is recorded somewhere?!?

Comment: I don't have time right now to write an answer, but all you are looking for should be in the $H_\infty$ book (in the computation of the homology of free $E_n$-spaces)

Comment: Thanks Denis. I am not sure why the $H_\infty$-structure is useful where one needs $E_\infty$ or $E_n$ structures to define the operations. On the other hand, I just realised that somehow, in an opposite direction, my question is answered (at least at the prime $2$) by Kuhn, in particular his paper ``The Transfer and James-Hopf Invariants'' is related ot my question, I think!

Comment: You only need the $H_n$-structure to define the operations, but that's pretty much irrelevant for the computations in the book I mentioned.

Comment: You're question is equivalent to the question "what is the homology of the free E_n-space on X?" and indeed, every element has a name in terms of the elements that appear from the pth filtration, together with the Browder bracket. This was computed by Cohen in "homology of iterated loop spaces" (but beware lots of mistakes if you want to use the literal formulas for computations)

Comment: @DylanWilson I know about homology of free $E_n$-spaces. The question is about construction of operations. For the moment, I am not worried about Browder operations or Cohen's top cell operation. Suppose $X=S^n$ so the aformentioned operations in $H_*\Omega^lS^{n+l}$ vanish and the homology is ``generated'' by Kudo-Araki (Dyer-Lashof) operations. These operations are defined only using $\theta_2$, so you defined $Q_ix=(\theta_2)_*(e_i\otimes x\otimes x)$. Say at the prime $2$, my question was about the role of $\theta_p$ with $p>2$ in this homology!? Surely, it has to be expressible in terms..

Comment: of $\theta_2$, right?!?

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks. Yes, $H_n$ would give operations with many similar properties. But, I think at least in the case of $H_\infty$ Nishida relations differ from what you get in $E_\infty$. So there is a pay off here! I want $E_\infty$ or $E_n$.

Comment: Elements of the homology of free En algebras *are* operations. All of them. So if you know about the homology of free En algebras then you already know the answer to your question. Every operation can be written as sums of products of compositions of the ones coming from what you call “theta p” (and also the Browder operation). Maybe I don’t understand your question?

Comment: @user51223 I'm pretty sure that the DL-operations coming from the $E_n$-structure are the same than the ones coming from the underlying $H_n$-structure: they're defined by the same formulas! To see the difference you need to go deeper, in the world of secondary operations

Comment: @DenisNardin Let's take $n=\infty$ case. According to May in `$H_\infty$ ring spectra and their applications' the Nishida relations in this case are different. I might be misunderstand something here, but to me it seems that beside many similar properties, we have different operations!?! I presume this should mean that if we have an $E_n$-space then the description of homology as $E_n$-space and $H_n$-space are the same!?! But, in general the operation we have are not the same! Maybe something on the operadic level is different which is not observable on the algebras over operads!!!

Comment: @DenisNardin But, returning to my own question, I think I might be able to do something just be degree considerations!!!

Comment: @user51223 Where is the difference of Nishida relations?  The one's on page 58 of $H_{\infty}$ is same as the one with $E_{\infty}$ spectra.

Comment: @user43326 I mean the paper published in Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, Vol. 32. 1978. At Page 235, there is announced that we have this difference, at least on the spectrum level. I might be wrong in assuming that they are different when used on the space-level.

Comment: @user51223 I cannot find any comment in this sense at page 235. I'm pretty sure you are misunderstanding. The DL operations are literally the same for H_∞ and E_∞-ring spectra. Let's not argue in comments anymore: if you have doubts please jump in the homotopy theory chatroom (I'm busy these days but I'm sure you'll find someone who can clear this)

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks. Just a few short comments.

Quoting last sentence of Comments before Theorem 3.1 of this paper "The key point is the Nishida relations, which are subtly different from their $E_\infty$ space level analogs". The coefficients for the Nishida relations are different(if not the formal expressions). Compare Theorem 3.1(7) of this paper to Theorem 1.1(9) of Part I in Cohen-May-Lada.
I should have also added comments after Theorem 3.1 of that paper.
This is is the reason to believe they are in general different.